# What is the probability that a student will get into vet school vs med school

Tags: probability

I am trying to explain what the probability of a student getting into vet school vs getting into med school with the following information:

there are 129 med schools in the united states
there are 29 vet schools in the united states

How do i set this up? Do i have enough information? im using this senario in a paper so if i need to research more information what do you suggest?

Comment: There isn't nearly enough information here.  In particular, you provide absolutely no information about any probabilities.

Comment: It's not really a problem of probability. Some students who perform well will ensure themselves a spot.

Comment: without any outside information based on how well the student did or anything like that, im trying to show that it is harder to get into vet school vs med school because there are not as many vet schools available. How could i turn this into a probability problem? i have to use probability in this paper

Comment: So say i had 10 students. Could i say "what are the chances that all of them will get into vet school"?

Comment: The number of schools is a very poor parameter. A slightly better parameter would be to look at raw statistics, like the number of applicants versus the number of open slots. Of course, this really doesn't tell us very much about any individual applicant.

Comment: The numbers of schools have very little to do with it.  More relevant would be the total numbers of students admitted to med schools and vet schools, and the numbers of applicants.  Divide the number of students admitted by the number of applicants, and you have the probability of a random applicant getting in.  But it's not really a fair comparison, because the populations of students who apply to vet school and med school are different.

Comment: Ok. Im probably going to have to change that entire paragraph to make something work. :(

Comment: Robert Israel I used your suggestion and made up an example. Thank you!